# Функция на python, которая вычисляет и возвращает стоимость корзины товаров после применения всех скидок

Tags: python, функции

Напишите функцию, которая вычисляет и возвращает стоимость корзины товаров после применения всех скидок. В качестве аргументов функция принимает 3 параметра:

•Общая сумма корзины

•Количество товаров в корзине

•Промокод

Правила и порядок (порядок важен!) начисления скидок:

•Если промокод равен 'ДАРИМ500', то из суммы вычитается 500 рублей. При этом если сумма меньше 500 рублей, то итоговая стоимость будет 0.

•При количестве товаров в корзине ≥10 применяется скидка 5% ко всей сумме

•При сумме, превышающей 100 000, применяется скидка 25% к сумме превышения (то есть к разнице суммы корзины и 100 000)

•
Если промокод равен 'СКИДКА10', то ко всей сумме применяется скидка 10%, но только если сумма ≥50 000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def sell(suma, col, promo):
    if promo=='ДАРИМ500':
        if suma<=500:
            suma = 0
        else:
            suma -= 500
    if col>=10:
        suma = (suma-(suma/100*5))
    if suma>=100000:
        suma = (suma-(suma/100*25))
    if promo=='СКИДКА10' and suma>=50000:
        suma = (suma-(suma/100*10))
```

Comment: Совсем забыл, если вам надо также в конце получить итоговою сумму то после всех проверок допишите: `return suma`

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @dudha369 по условию скидка 25% применяется к сумме превышения _(то есть к разнице суммы корзины и 100 000)_

Comment: @somedumbass Если ответ вам помог, то будьте добры поставить галочку слева от ответа